# "Interface name is not valid at this point"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

```
public IEnumerable<decimal> SomeKeys
{
    get
    {
        return dbContext.SomeTable.Select(x=>x.Key);
    }
}

public IEnumerable<decimal> SomeOtherKeys
{
    get
    {
        var ret = IEnumerable<decimal>(); // interface name is not 
                                          // valid as this point
        // do stuff with ret
        return ret;
    }
}
```

With my current code, I'm getting the exception above.

Do I have to return a `List<decimal>`? Or how am I supposed to return the `IEnumerable` or `IQueriable` datatypes?

Comment: they are interfaces, not really "data types". i think a basic tutorial on interfaces will make this problem clear :c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is  `var ret = IEnumerable<decimal>();`  just not valid `C#` code, that is.

You may want to do something like:

```
var ret = new List<decimal>();
```

Remeber that [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), quoting documentation, derives from `IEnumerable<T>` too.

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, 
    IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, 
    IEnumerable
```

so the code like

```
public IEnumerable<decimal> SomeOtherKeys
{
    get
    {
        var ret = new List<decimal>();                                          
        // do stuff with ret
        return ret;
    }
}
```

is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

In your `SomeOtherKeys` property getter, you have to instantiate a class that implements the `IEnumerable<decimal>` interface.

Changing to `List<decimal>` would be fine.

```
var ret = new List<decimal>();
ret.Add(1.0M);
ret.Add(2.0M);
```

Answer (score 1):

You create class instances but never interfaces as they are just code contracts but can't be instantiated.

You have to pick the collection implementing `IEnumerable<T>` that suit better for your scenario and stick with it.

Your property `SomeOtherKeys` can keep the signature, no need to change it as using an interface as return value is totally valid and a good practice as helps to reduce coupling